# Styling each option in dropdown in Yii

Tags: php, yii, html-select

I have a dropdown

```
    $Customer=Customer::getDecisionMakingCompany();
    $div_topic.= CHtml::dropDownList('picks_customer_id',"picks_customer_id",$Customer,array('multiple'=>true));
```

List is coming from the model

```
public static function getDecisionMakingCompany() {
    $condition = 'status=  "Y" AND type=1';
    $model = self::model()->findAll(array('condition' => $condition,'order'=>'customer_name'));
    return CHtml::listData($model, 'id', 'customer_name');
}
```

Each customer have a color in database. How can i give that color to option text. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make following changes in your Model and View Files:

### View File

```
$Customer = Customer::getDecisionMakingCompany();

echo CHtml::tag('select', array('id' => 'picks_customer_id', 'name' => 'picks_customer_id[]', 'multiple' => true));

if (!empty($Customer)) {
        foreach ($Customer as $index => $cust) {        
                echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $cust->id, 'style' => 'color:' . $cust->color), $CHtml::encode($cust->customer_name), true);
        }
}
```

### Model File

```
public static function getDecisionMakingCompany() {
    $condition = 'status=""Y"" AND type=1';
    $model = self::model()->findAll(array('condition' => $condition, 'order'=>'customer_name'));
    return $model;
}
```

Hope this help you! Let me know if there is any concern from this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the htmlOption for each value this way:

```
$Customer=Customer::getDecisionMakingCompany();
$div_topic.= CHtml::dropDownList('picks_customer_id',"picks_customer_id",
      $Customer,array('multiple'=>true, 
          array( 'value1'=>array('style'=>'color: yourColor1', ),   
                 'value2'=>array('style'=>'color: yourColor2'),
           ));
```